# Powershell regex match _ 3 times

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a variable array `$nom` which contains:

```
cg42_7zip_9.22.xml
cg42_AdobeAir_22.0.0.153.xml
cg42_agent_EPO_5.0.5.568.xml
cg42_Java_8u101.xml
```

I want to extract the name and the version of each line. I want my result to be like this:

```
Name          Version
7zip          9.22
AdobeAir      22.0.0.153
agent_EPO     5.0.5.568
Java          8u101
```

Comment: This question could have done with showing some effort, but I don't agree that it was "Too broad". This is apparent by the fact that it got 4 answers.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. They are all correct and allowed me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Other method, with regex into split :

```
$nom = 'cg42_7zip_9.22.xml','cg42_AdobeAir_22.0.0.153.xml','cg42_agent_EPO_5.0.5.568.xml','cg42_Java_8u101.xml'
$nom | %{$tb=$_ -split "(\S+)_(\S+)\.(\S+)"; [pscustomobject]@{Name=$tb[1];Version=$tb[2]}}
```

Comment: To have desired output modify to `-split "_(\S+)_(\S+)\.(\S+)$"` +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

```
$nom = 'cg42_7zip_9.22.xml','cg42_AdobeAir_22.0.0.153.xml','cg42_agent_EPO_5.0.5.568.xml','cg42_Java_8u101.xml'

$nom | ForEach-Object {
    $FirstUnderscore = $_.IndexOf('_')
    $LastUnderscore = $_.LastIndexOf('_')
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property ([Ordered]@{
        Name = $_.substring($FirstUnderscore+1,$LastUnderscore-$FirstUnderscore-1)
        Version = $_.substring($LastUnderscore+1) -replace '\.xml'
    })
}
```

Result:

```
Name      Version   
----      -------   
7zip      9.22      
AdobeAir  22.0.0.153
agent_EPO 5.0.5.568 
Java      8u101
```

This assumes you are always dealing with .xml file names.

- Uses the `.IndexOf` method to get the position of the first `_` character.
- Uses the `.LastIndexOf` method to get the position in the string of the last `_` character.
- Uses the `.SubString` method to get the part of the string from the first underscore, up to the index of the last underscore.
- Uses substring to get the rest of the string starting from the position after the last underscore and removing the `.xml` part with a `-replace`.
- Outputs the result as a PowerShell object with Name and Version properties. Uses an `[ordered]` hashtable to return the properties in the order they are defined (note this requires PS v3).

Answer (score 1):

try this ;)

```
$nom = 'cg42_7zip_9.22.xml','cg42_AdobeAir_22.0.0.153.xml','cg42_agent_EPO_5.0.5.568.xml','cg42_Java_8u101.xml'

$nom | %{
$Array=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_) -split "_"; 
[pscustomobject]@{Name=$Array[1..($Array.Length - 2)] -join "_";Version=$Array[-1]} 
}
```

Comment: I have modifed my code ty

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw in another variant:

```
$nom = 'cg42_7zip_9.22.xml','cg42_AdobeAir_22.0.0.153.xml','cg42_agent_EPO_5.0.5.568.xml','cg42_Java_8u101.xml'
ForEach ($i in ($nom).TrimEnd('.xml')){$n,$v=$i.split('_')[1,2];[PSCustomObject]@{Name=$n;Version=$v}}
```

Sample output:

```
Name     Version
----     -------
7zip     9.22
AdobeAir 22.0.0.153
agent    EPO
Java     8u101
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work as you can see by the output of agent_EPO, it's not supporting where there might be more than 1 underscore.

Comment: @MarkWragg Didn't recognize that 3rd underscore, since there are 3 working solutions I'll delete my answer soon.